# trouble getting an array in PHP into a javascript function that is injected back to the web page

Tags: php, jquery

In a JQuery Dialog, I show the user a list of posts in a database that they can access. This comes from a first PHP script. The user selects a post and actions are taken in the database by a second PHP script. Parts of this work, but I can't get an array to be processed, POSTed, to the second PHP script that performs a query with the array data.

The sequence starts with a jQuery ajax POST. The Firebug Console shows me correct data in the POST and lists them as array elements, e.g., field[] abc, field[] xyz, etc. The first PHP, editPost.php, receives a string, which works, and secondly the array as

```
$propertyFields = array();
$propertyFields = $_POST[ 'propertyFields' ];
```

After the first script's query completes using the string, but not the array, a while loop constructs the list of selection items, and populates a javascript function that works -sort of. It provides list descriptions, but does not work to include the array of propertyFields - that should go the the second PHP script.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $activeCount = mysql_real_escape_string($row["activeCount"]);
    $error_NumberOfActives = "<ul>Welcome back.
    <br>Click the 'Edit this one' button that you want to edit or change.
    <script type='text/javascript'>var properTFields=[]; //added array declaration,but no fix
    function retrievePost( idx, propertyID, properTFields ) {
//retrieve database content for clicked post and changes text message inside the button 
    alert( properTFields + '|in editPost' ); //test - get - function Array() {[native code]}|in editPost
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '../phpFunctions/editPostUpdate.php',  
        data:{  properTID: propertyID, //POSTs OK
                propertyFields: properTFields //propertyFields is empty in POST to editPostUpdate.php                          },                                   
        type:'POST',                                       
        success: function (data) {
            if (data ) {
            //button reads 'can now be changed' from editPostUpdate.php with forced success from editPostUpdate.php.
                document.getElementById(idx).innerHTML = propertyID + ' can now be changed';
            //alert(data); //get forced success message from editPostUpdate.php
            } else {
            document.getElementById(idx).innerHTML = propertyID + ' has errors,check,try again';
            }

        }
    });
    }</script></ul>";
//some messages are constructed in PHP objects - nothing to do with this problem
    //make HTML list items of active postings for 3Step countries
    $idMaker = "active" . $rowCount;
    //this syntax is exceptionally picky. It took advice from gurus and hours of trials to get it. It works with the retrievePost function above.
    //test - $propertyFields was added as a function variable. It doesn't work. 
    $error_ListActives = "<li> $propertyID, $storedStreetAddress, $storedCity3
    <button type='button' id='$idMaker' onclick='retrievePost( id, $propertyID, $propertyFields )'>Edit this one</button>
    </li>";
```

Note that in the list items, the variables for propertyID, storedStreetAddress, and storedCity3 all work and display in the injected HTML from the retrievePost function above it. Its just the $propertyFields array that does not work. In the POST data, Firebug Console shows a string for properTID, and an empty field for the propertyFields array.

When the user selects via a button, I want the propertyFields array POSTed to a second PHP script, editPostUpdate.php, as shown, where the array of data will be used in a query. This POST happens, but its an empty array. I have tried a lot of things, including the original javascript array as the element connected to data: propertyFields:   No success.  What should be done?

Comment: what's the question (in one line) ?

Comment: Your html is highly invalid. You've got a `<ul>` but no `<li>` tags. you're dumping out a `<script>` block for each of those `<ul>`'s as well, and since nothing in the ajax code is changing within the loop, you'll simply be doing the SAME ajax call each time.

Comment: @Dagon, In 1 line - After a user selects a post in injected HTML, how to pass an array of web page id's to another PHP script for its query?

Comment: @MarcB, I'm showing only relevant code. I think the problem is in the last line of code ($error_ListActives, which is an <li>) or in something about the retrievePost function. The HTML gives me a nice, numberical list of posts, their descriptions, and a summary starting welcome message. Your thoughts on the described problem could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The clue to the source of the problem is in "populates a javascript function that works - sort of. It provides list descriptions, but does not work to include the array of propertyFields" So what's wrong with the array??  It took me a tremendously long time, but I found that an array of strings is not understood by Javascript in this case. I mistakenly thought strings would be simpler. When I changed the properTFields array to JSON, with the json_encode() command  - bang - the code, as written above, worked on the first try. Moral of the story: use JSON with Javascript.